# Drupal Lightbox 2 how to remove unnecessary scroll bars?

Tags: drupal, lightbox, scrollbars

Whenever I use Drupal's Lightbox 2 module to display videos it always adds ugly scroll bars which are unnecessary. How can I get the module to stop showing the scroll bars or find out why it thinks they are needed in the first place. Here is a sample page on my website you can see what I am talking about. http://www.yoninja.com/jp/dailylife/600/seibo-catholic-hospital-shinjuku. If you click on the video at the bottom of the page you will see it load with scroll bars.

Comment: the iframe has **"id=lightboxFrame"** which contain the video has the inline style define as **scrolling: auto** and that can't be controlled through css you can write a external script code which forcefully remove that property.

Comment: through the firebug tool you can see which element has the problem, in your case it's a body inside the iframe that contain video, see my answer to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Enable iframe border. You can modify the border style in your theme's css file using the iframe's id "lightboxFrame".
> ```

Try this. #lightboxFrame{overflow:hidden}

Answer (score 0):

just write a new definition for the class `emvideo-modal-iframe` in your theme style.css 
 like 
`.emvideo-modal-iframe{overflow:hidden;}`